# Deploy REST API with HTTP Endpoint Integration using SAM AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, devops, serverless, serverless-application-model

I'm new to AWS SAM deployment. I have a use case to automate the deployment using SAM AWS. Having a Rest API GW with another HTTP endpoint invocation. I searched pretty more docs but I didn't find any solution for this. Could you mind suggest me how to do this case?

Thanks in advance.
Karthikeyan B

Comment: Do you have trouble creating the REST API with SAM? Or automating the deployment?

Comment: @SurajBhatia Issue on creating a Rest API having an HTTP endpoint invocation through SAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample template you can try for creating integration -

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: AWS SAM template with a HTTP integration
Resources:
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: prod
      DefinitionBody: {
        "swagger": "2.0",
        "info": {
          "version": "1.0"
        },
        "paths": {
          "test": {
            "get": {
              "produces": [
                "application/json"
              ],
              "responses": {
                "200": {
                  "description": "200 response"
                }
              },
              "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                "responses": {
                  "default": {
                    "statusCode": "200"
                  }
                },
                "credentials": "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/role-name",
                "uri": "https://www.example.com",
                "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
                "httpMethod": "GET",
                "type": "http_proxy"
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Deploy the template using [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-deploying.html) -

> $ sam deploy --stack-name httpProxy -t httpProxy.yaml --capabilities
> CAPABILITY_IAM

Comment: Is there a way where we can avoid using a swagger definition in 'DefinitionBody' ?

Comment: You can link to a swagger definition using `DefinitionUri`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can build a hello world SAM app in a few clicks using the AWS toolkit in VS Code as shown in my blog post [here](https://harishkm.in/2020/06/23/create-deploy-rest-api-backed-by-node-js-12-lambda-using-aws-sam/).
2. Then, modify the generated SAM template (`template.yaml`) to integrate with an HTTP API instead of Lambda.
3. Add a `buildspec.yml` to your codebase & build a CI/CD pipeline using AWS CodeBuild & CodePipeline as shown in my blog post [here](https://harishkm.in/2020/06/23/automate-build-deployment-of-aws-sam-app-using-aws-codebuild-codepipeline/).

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. 
Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Thanks, @Yatin. I've edited the answer to disclose my affiliation with the links in my answer.